# How can I learn to make my own packages?

Tags: macros

I can say I know how to create documents in LaTeX. However, I want to learn more. I would like to know how to learn to create my own packages. It may be a bit presumptuous for a beginner, but at least I would like to learn to do some of my own things! For instance, make beautiful designs for chapters, write codes (macros), etc. What language is used?

I would be grateful if you can recommend some good book.

Comment: Welcome to our corner of the SE world! Related/useful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/where-do-i-start-latex-programming

Comment: you may have expected the response, but afaik there are no books about programming packages, so the only possible way is to thread your way through books, existing code ... and existing posts on the subject.

Comment: ... however, you _do_ need a thorough grounding in knuth's tex book.  beyond that, the only way is to hack your way through some representative packages (and of course the latex source code), and ask when you get stuck.  remember, there are lots of sticking points, and you don't want to use up good-will by asking every time you stumble: when you do, try again, looking at relevant code (and its friends and relatives) again...

Comment: ... and finally, the _latex companion_ (2nd ed) may help a bit: it has coding examples which may help.